# Error 13117 while setting up master-slave replication with both DB servers being on the same Mac M1 machine

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication, macos

I am trying to create a master-slave replication with both the Mysql Servers being on the same machine.

The first mysql server, which I intend to keep as the master was installed using the Mysql Native Package Installer mentioned [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/macos-installation-pkg.html)

Following is the `my.cnf` configuration file used for the above master server.

Location of the file: `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
server-id=1 #was confused which one is the correct server-id key, thus added both of them.
server_id=1
log-bin=mysql-bin-master
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Once the above was done, I started the master Mysql Server using the Mysql Preference Pane in MacOS (the last tab in System Preferences on Mac)

Following is the `my.ini` configuration for the Slave.

Location of the file: `/etc/my.ini`

```
[mysqld]
server-id=2
server_id=2
log-bin=mysql-bin-slave
relay-log=relay-log-bin
log-slave-updates=1
read-only=1
replicate-ignore-db=mysql
replicate-do-db=mydatabase
replicate-ignore-table=mydatabase.logs
replicate-wild-ignore-table=mydatabase.temp_%
master-info-repository=TABLE
relay-log-info-repository=TABLE
replicate-same-server-id=1
```

Thereafter, I tried to setup the slave mysql server instance using the following command:

```
sudo mysqld --user=mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/replica/data --port=3307 --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/replica/data/error.log --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/replica/data/mysql.pid --defaults-file=/etc/my.ini
```

I had created a replica folder inside `/usr/local/mysql/` where all of the data files for replica could be kept.

I created a user account on the Master with the following command:

`CREATE USER 'replica'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`

and granted replication access via `GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replica'@'%';`

Thereafter, tried logging in to the SLAVE Mysql console and start replication via:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='localhost', MASTER_USER='replica', MASTER_PASSWORD='password', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin-master.000001', MASTER_LOG_POS=157;
START SLAVE;
```

But when I do, `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`, I get the following error:

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State:
                  Master_Host: localhost
                  Master_User: replica
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin-master.000001
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 157
               Relay_Log_File: Karans-Air-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 123456
              Relay_Log_Space: 697
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 13117
                Last_IO_Error: Fatal error: The replica I/O thread stops because source and replica have equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be different for replication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on replica but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it).
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID:
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Replica has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 230423 18:02:08
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
       Master_public_key_path:
        Get_master_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace:
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Also, checked the MASTER_LOG_POS already and MASTER_LOG_FILE. Both of them are correct!

Comment: What does `SELECT @@server_id;` return on the replica? (I use the terms _source_ and _replica_ instead of _master_ and _slave_).

Comment: I'd recommend setting `SOURCE_HOST='127.0.0.1'` to make it clear you're using the TCP port. Replication is supposed to work only via TCP, so 'localhost' shouldn't work via the UNIX socket, but it may need to be explicit.

Comment: @BillKarwin It was returning 1 on both `source` and `replica`. Where should I set the `SOURCE_HOST` variable ? Is this to be added in the `my.cnf` and `my.ini` files ?

Comment: Edit: Found this, but now facing issue in opening port 3307 on my mac os ventura. Trying to resolve the same.

Comment: SOURCE_HOST is the equivalent of MASTER_HOST. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/change-replication-source-to.html